# How to assign values to structs that are embedded

Tags: c

If I have 2 struct, one of the struct is used as a datatype for one of the members of the other structs, how do i assign values if the struct used as a datatype is already assigned values.

```
typedef struct
{datatype *a;datatype b;datatype c;} structa;
typedef struct
{datatype a;structa *b;}structb;

structa A[]={{&a, b, c}, {&d, e, f}};
structb B={g, &A};
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: due to the nature of my codes i cannot share the exact codes but that the way i am doing. can compile but there is a warning on the second struct.

Comment: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Comment: @KennyQuahKokSiong Even if you cannot post the current code you have, create a new, complete example that others can copy/paste to compile and see the same error that you see on your screen - this will make it a lot easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

There is a simple demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct A
{
    int a1;
    int a2;
} A;

typedef struct B
{
    A ba;
    A *pba;
    int b1;
    int b2;
} B;

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    A a;
    B b1, b2;
    a = (A) {1, 2};
    b1 = (B) {a, &a, 3, 4};
    b2 = (B) {a, &a, 5, 6};

    B bs1[] = {b1, b2};
    B bs2[] = {(B){a, &a, 7, 8},(B){a, &a, 9, 10}};

    printf("a: {%d, %d}, addr of a: %p\n", a.a1, a.a2, &a);
    printf("b1: {{%d, %d}, %p, %d, %d}\n", b1.ba.a1, b1.ba.a2, b1.pba, b1.b1, b1.b2);
    printf("b2: {{%d, %d}, %p, %d, %d}\n", b2.ba.a1, b2.ba.a2, b2.pba, b2.b1, b2.b2);
    printf("bs1[0]: {{%d, %d}, %p, %d, %d}\n", bs1[0].ba.a1, bs1[0].ba.a2, bs1[0].pba, bs1[0].b1, bs1[0].b2);
    printf("bs1[1]: {{%d, %d}, %p, %d, %d}\n", bs1[1].ba.a1, bs1[1].ba.a2, bs1[1].pba, bs1[1].b1, bs1[1].b2);
    printf("bs2[0]: {{%d, %d}, %p, %d, %d}\n", bs2[0].ba.a1, bs2[0].ba.a2, bs2[0].pba, bs2[0].b1, bs2[0].b2);
    printf("bs2[1]: {{%d, %d}, %p, %d, %d}\n", bs2[1].ba.a1, bs2[1].ba.a2, bs2[1].pba, bs2[1].b1, bs2[1].b2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
a: {1, 2}, addr of a: 0x7fffb2040240
b1: {{1, 2}, 0x7fffb2040240, 3, 4}
b2: {{1, 2}, 0x7fffb2040240, 5, 6}
bs1[0]: {{1, 2}, 0x7fffb2040240, 3, 4}
bs1[1]: {{1, 2}, 0x7fffb2040240, 5, 6}
bs2[0]: {{1, 2}, 0x7fffb2040240, 7, 8}
bs2[1]: {{1, 2}, 0x7fffb2040240, 9, 10}
```

Answer (score -1):

Short answere: No.

Medium answere: foo.c:8:15: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Long answer: &A is the address of the array of structa, a pointer to an array of structa. But structb requires a pointer to structa only. Otherwise it is correct.

Comment: `&A` is __not__ a pointer to pointer to `structa`. It is a pointer to an array of `structa`.

Comment: array can be implicitly converted to pointers to the first element if the context requires it so `A` instead of `&A` should work

Comment: @KennyQuahKokSiong You get rid of the warning by using the right type. `&A[0]` or simply `A` will do. Or change the type in structb.

Comment: Note: The correct type in structb to allow use of &A would be `structa (*b)[]`.